# Optimizing query for large number of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, index, performance, performance-tuning

I have the following database table in MySQL :

[image]

and is running the following query

```
SELECT `scratch_tickets`.`id` AS ticket_id, `scratch_tickets`.`created_at`, `scratch_tickets`.`prize_type`, `scratch_tickets`.`prize`, `scratch_tickets`.`is_win`, `scratch_tickets`.`game_id` FROM (`scratch_tickets`)  WHERE `scratch_tickets`.`created_at` >='2015-02-12 00:00:00' and created_at<='2015-02-18 23:59:59' AND `scratch_tickets`.`status` = 4 LIMIT 50;
```

Now the EXPLAIN is giving following results

[image]

The query is taking almost 35 seconds to execute and when I use this with PHP, it is getting timed out. Here I think the indexes being utilized. How can I optimize this for a better performance ?

The table already have 25708614 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT scratch_tickets.id AS ticket_id, 
       -- more columns
FROM (scratch_tickets)  
WHERE scratch_tickets.created_at >='2015-02-12 00:00:00' 
  AND created_at <= '2015-02-18 23:59:59' 
  AND scratch_tickets.status = 4 
LIMIT 50 ;
```

needs a simple index on `(status, created_at)`:

```
ALTER TABLE scratch_tickets
  ADD INDEX status_created_at_idx         -- pick a name for the index
  (status, created_at) ;
```

After testing that the query is using the new index and is more efficient, you can probably drop the old `status` index. (*"probably"* because you may have some rare query that profits a lot from a `(status)` index but is slow when using the `(status, created_at)` one.)

Some more notes:

- Having `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is a recipe for indeterminate results. Always use `ORDER BY` so you are in control of which (50) rows will be chosen for return (unless you really don't mind semi-random results or there are serious performance issues).
- Also note that adding or changing the `ORDER BY` expression may affect performance. For the specific query, the index will be used effectively if you have `ORDER BY created_at` or `ORDER BY created_at DESC` or `ORDER BY created_at, ticket_id`. If a different column or expression is used, the efficiency may not be as good.
- Instead of inclusive (`>=` and `<=` - or `BETWEEN`) it's easier and less error-prone to use inclusive-exclusive ranges for datetime types. This way, you don't care much if the type is `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` or if it has second, millisecond or microsecond accuracy.
- Queries are more clear with aliases. See a rewrite:

  ```
  SELECT st.id AS ticket_id, 
         -- more columns
  FROM scratch_tickets AS st
  WHERE at.created_at >= '2015-02-12 00:00:00'       -- you could even use '2015-02-12'
    AND st.created_at <  '2015-02-19 00:00:00'       -- notice the   < 
    AND st.status = 4 
  ORDER BY <some_expression>
  LIMIT 50 ;
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot I haven't added the index yet but the order by has reduced the number of rows scanning to 6220974

Comment: What expression/column did you use for the order by? And is it an InnoDB or MyISAM table?

Comment: This is InnoDB. I used ORDER BY created_at

Comment: Good, I edited the answer but the index should be used with that order by.